# To prove that $\tan70=\tan20+2\tan50$

Tags: trigonometry

to prove that $$\tan70=\tan20+2\tan50$$

Now i wrote $70=20+50$ and took $\tan$ on both sides and after cross multiplying i have got to $\tan70 -\tan20\tan50\tan70=\tan20+\tan50$. how do i proced?

thanks

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861288/on-the-proof-tan-70-tan-20-2-tan-40-4-tan-10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\tan70 - \tan 20 & =\dfrac{\sin 70}{\cos 70}-\dfrac{\sin20}{\cos20}\\
& =\dfrac{\sin70\cos20-\cos70\sin20}{\cos20\cos70}\\
& =\dfrac{\sin(70-20)}{\cos20  \cos 70}\\
& =\dfrac{\sin50}{\cos 20 \cos 70}\\
&=\dfrac{\sin50}{\cos20 .\sin(20)}\\
&=\dfrac{\color{red} {2}\sin50}{\color{red} {2}\sin20.\cos 20 }\\
&=\dfrac{\color{red} {2}\sin50}{\sin40 }\\
&=\dfrac{\color{red} {2}\sin50}{\cos(90-40) }\\
&=\dfrac{\color{red} {2}\sin50}{\cos50}\\
&=2\tan50
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

**Generalization** :

$$\tan(90^\circ-A)-\tan A=\cot A-\tan A=\cdots=2\cot2A=2\tan(90^\circ-2A)$$

Answer (score 1):

i got this . just noticed $\tan70\tan20=1$

Comment: Sophie: I remember solving one of your posts a while back. Which country are you living in?

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that $$\tan70^{\circ}-\tan50^{\circ}=\tan20^{\circ}+\tan50^{\circ}$$ or
$$\frac{\sin20^{\circ}}{\cos70^{\circ}\cos50^{\circ}}=\frac{\sin70^{\circ}}{\cos20^{\circ}\cos50^{\circ}},$$
which is obvious because $\sin20^{\circ}=\cos70^{\circ}$ and $\sin70^{\circ}=\cos20^{\circ}$